# How to Implement "Railway Pattern" in Kotlin/Arrow.kt for producer Channel

Tags: android, kotlin, arrow-kt

I'm investigating Kotlin Coroutines & Channels in my current Android application.

I have the following code that manages remote Api calls and controls UI Side effects

```
   private val historical: CompletableDeferred<List<Any>> = CompletableDeferred()
   private val mutex = Mutex()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun perform(action: Action): ReceiveChannel<List<Any>> =
        produce {

          mutex.withLock {
            if (historical.isCompleted) {
                send(historical.getCompleted())
                return@produce
            }  

            send(action.sideEffects)
            val networkResponse = repository.perform(action)
            send(networkResponse.sideEffects)
            send(listOf(networkResponse)).also {
                    historical.complete(listOf(response))
                }
            }
        }
```

The above code gives me the desired result, however I would like to refactor it to something resembling
the Functional Programming "Railway Pattern" https://android.jlelse.eu/real-world-functional-programming-with-kotlin-arrow-b5a98e72f5e3

where my process flow is

```
stepOne(Historical.completed)
.stepTwo(action.sideEffects)
.stepThree(getReaction())
.stepFour(reaction.sideEffects)
.finalStep(reaction)
```

which will "short circuit" on either failures of any step or when Historical "isCompleted"

is it possible to achieve this style of call in Kotlin? and/or Kotlin & Arrow.kt?

Comment: Not sure what your code does.... but yes it is possible to achieve Railway oriented programming with Kotlin and Arrow. Check this out: https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/monad_comprehensions/

Comment: If each returns an observable you might be able to do it like this. See RxJava and RxKotlin

Comment: Railway oriented programming concept works in Kotlin by **infix functions** for the same type of input and output with differed results. Can you provide some more info on your code *(What are functions and I/O)* so that I can better help you with your approach?

Comment: You can implement ROP without Arrow - https://gist.github.com/harikrishnan83/3c4359bbb91e57eba7b962dc9300c6cc. Even with Arrow "Either" the code can look little less readable (The FlatMaps can get in the way of the steps reading like the way you have written in your question). You may need need to add an infix on top of that https://gist.github.com/harikrishnan83/a16ef8f2e6f9287482adc2b29fbb23f2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Arrow-kt's [Either](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core-data/arrow.core/-either/).

You can use `Either's` `mapLeft()`, `map()`, `flatMap()`.

In case result is `Exception` use `mapLeft()`. Returned value from `mapLeft()` going to be new `Left` in result `Either`, for example return is `String`, result going to be `Either<String, List<Any>>`. In case result is `Right`, ie `List<Any>`, `mapLeft()` going to be skipped, but result type changes anyway, so you will have type of `Either<String, List<Any>>` with value of `Right<List<Any>>`. You can also return same `Exception` from `mapLeft()` if you choose so

I case you have no need in handling specific errors, you can just chain `map()` and `flatMap()`. `map()` is basically mapRight() and `flatMap()` is useful when you want to chain calls, ie somewhere in chain there is a receiver of `List<Any>` which can fail and you want to handle `Exception` the same way with `Either` for that call, you can just return new `Either` from `flatMap()`

Code gonna look something like this

```
fun perform(action: Either<Exception, Action>): ReceiveChannel<List<Any>> =
    produce {
        // if action is always right, you can start it as Right(action) but then first mapLeft does not make any sense
        if (historical.completed) action
            .mapLeft {
                // handle actions exception here
                // transform it to something else or just return it
                send(action.sideEffects)
                it
            }.flatMap {
                // handle right side of action either
                // assume here that repository may fail and returns Either<Exception, NetworkResponse>
                repository.perform(it)
            }.mapLeft {
                // handle repositorys exception here
                // transform it to something else or just return it
                send(it)
                it
            }.map {
                // handle network response
                send(listOf(networkResponse))
                historical.complete(listOf(networkResponse))
            }
    }
```

Comment: I wonder why there is no .onLeft { ... } method on Either types. Doing a mapLeft works, of course, but having to return "it" all the time is awkward. I prefer .also { if (it.isLeft()) ... } currently. Alternatively .apply { if (isLeft()) ... }

Comment: @Zordid I guess so you can chain one call after another and handle errors for all of them in one place. Otherwise, you can return about nothing. Custom extension function .onLeft will do the job I guess. And iirc in real product we had .mapLeftReturn extension function which ommited returns